# In Paillier homomorphism, how do you deal with bit length?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I'm trying to figure out homomorphic encryption and would like to multiply two paillier encrypted numbers. 
Like so: 
[a].[b]=[a+b]

To try this I got this [Paillier.java](http://liris.cnrs.fr/~ohasan/pprs/paillierdemo/Paillier.java) and tried the following:

```
BigInteger Paillier p = new Paillier (2048);
BigIntegera=p.encrypt(BigInteger.valueOf(12345));
BigInteger b=p.encrypt(BigInteger.valueOf(54321));
BigInteger c=a.multiply(b);
BigInteger res=p.decrypt(c)
```

Except this gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Paillier.decrypt(BigInteger c): ciphertext c is not in Z*_{n^2}
    at pet4.Paillier.decrypt(Paillier.java:180)
    at pet4.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Now looking at the bitcount of `c` I can see that it's above 4000 (it varies a bit). So how do we deal with the fact that multiplying paillier encryped numbers results in larger bitcounts?

Comment: It is important to note that this operation is needed because you are not really working with integers, you are working on $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. It means that if you try to add two integers which sums to a value bigger than $n$, you will not decrypt to the expected value.

Comment: I hate to self promote here, but I think you will find [my Paillier library](https://github.com/mikeazo/thep) much easier to use. Some reasons to use mine: 1) mine supports homomorphic operations out of the box, no need to implement them yourself; 2) mine allows you to specify a class to use other than BigInteger, so you can use a library that uses native code for the expensive BigInteger operations, which is way faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the fact that your $c$ value can get waaay beyond what the library is expecting there and thus issues an error which can be read as "your value is too large".

The solution is simple: Reduce the multiplication result $\bmod N^2$, where $N=pq$ is the actual value of your modulus.

The code-line which you would need to add there would then be

```
 c=c.remained(p.getNsquare())
```

after the multiplication.